# Selenium-wire Как отключить сообщения в консоль

Tags: python, selenium

Парсер сайта стоит на сервере Ubuntu22.04. При запуске парсера начинает сыпать сообщениями типа
INFO:seleniumwire.handler:Capturing request:
INFO:seleniumwire.handler:Capturing response:
Как можно выключить отправку этих сообщений

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')


options_proxy = {
'proxy':{
    'http': f'http://{proxy[1]}:{proxy[2]}@{proxy[0]}',
    'https': f'https://{proxy[1]}:{proxy[2]}@{proxy[0]}',
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/Bot/chromedriver',chrome_options=options, 
seleniumwire_options=options_proxy)
```

Answer (score 0):

это относится к настройке логгирования

вам нужно найти

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

либо

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

и поправить на

```
logging.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
```

или

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET)
```

см. документацию https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html